# Error When Unwrapping Optional Element

Tags: json, swift, null, option-type

I have an optional element, but am facing an error when displaying said element in a tableview. For reference, this element is an image, obtained from a JSON API feed. I understand that force unwrapping an element using ! is not a good idea, but it is what xcode suggests I do, giving me no other options. If I follow its suggestion, the app crashes, displaying **"unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value."** Does anyone know how I can display an image from a URL. Here is the code I have thus far.

```
struct PlayerStats:Decodable {
    let personaname: String?
    let score: Double?
    let solo_competitive_rank: Int?
    let avatar: String?
}
```

The Problem is with the "avatar" element, in the cellForRowAt func.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "rankCell") as? RankTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
    cell.nameLabel.text = rank[indexPath.row].personaname

    if let imageURL = URL(string: rank[indexPath.row].avatar) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
            if let data = data {
            guard let avatar = UIImage(data: data) else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.avatarImage.image = avatar
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Even though by dispatching `Data(contentsOf: imageURL)`, you won't be blocking the main thread, that initializer of `Data` shouldn't be used for downloading content from the internet. That initializer should only be used for loading content from a __local__ file URL, not a network URL.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. I'm just basing this knowledge off of the material I've learned thus far, so I was unaware of this issue.

Comment: *"it is what xcode suggests I do"* - I think half of the Swift questions on this site are caused by this lovely "feature" of Xcode. I really hope Apple changes this someday soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code crashes if `avatar` is `nil`. You need to create the URL in two steps

```
if let avatar = rank[indexPath.row].avatar,
   let imageURL = URL(string: avatar) { ...
```

Alternatively decode `avatar` directly to URL, `JSONDecoder` can that

```
let avatar: URL?
```

Then you can shorten the code

```
if let imageURL = rank[indexPath.row].avatar {
```

And you are strongly discouraged from using synchronous `Data(contentsOf:` API as mentioned by Dávid. Use asynchronous `URLSession`

Answer (score 1):

Other than the fact that you need to safely unwrap the optional `avatar` property, there are several conceptual issues with your code.

First of all, you should never be performing asynchronous operations inside `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`, since this is a synchronous method, so the `UITableViewCell` will be returned before the image could be downloaded from the network URL. You need to perform the image downloading in a separate function and reloading the table view (or at least the corresponding row/section) once the asynchronous operation finishes execution.

Secondly, don't use the initializer `Data(contentsOf:)` for downloading content from the internet. Even though by dispatching `Data(contentsOf: imageURL)`, you won't be blocking the main thread, that initializer of Data shouldn't be used for downloading content from the internet. That initializer should only be used for loading content from a local file URL, not a network URL.